Using Apify Proxy With Playwright
So , i Trying To use Playwright Python Script headless With Apify trial Proxy inAnd Run it in Apify Console.
I always Get different Error When Trying To use thire proxies
Nx_proxy error......etc
I know that they don't allow the use of thire trial proxy outside apify.
Can someone give the right code to use thire proxy with Playwright in thire console....
I tried


from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright



# Set your proxy server and authentication credentials

proxy_server = 'your_proxy_server_address'

proxy_username = 'your_proxy_username'

proxy_password = 'your_proxy_password'



with sync_playwright() as p:

    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)

    page = browser.new_page()

    

    # Configure proxy settings

    await page.context.set_http_proxy({

        'server': proxy_server,

        'username': proxy_username,

        'password': proxy_password

    })

    

    # Navigate to a URL that requires proxy authentication

    await page.goto('https://example.com')

    

    # Continue with your scraping or automation tasks

    # ...

    

    await browser.close()













